# Trouble with a timestamp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, timestamp

I have been having trouble with getting a timestamp to work with a certain set of conditions.
I need it to give me a timestamp on two different columns once the conditions are met. The first timestamp should appear when the second column gets fill out (this part is actually working).
The second timestamp should appear on the 7 column only when the word "COMPLETE" is selected out of a drop-down list, something that's not happening since no matter whats chosen out of the list the timestamp appears an I'm not sure where the issue is at.

This is the code I have been using for this:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Notes" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();

    if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { //checks the column 
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      //if( nextCell.getValue() !== '' ) //is empty?
      nextCell.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "MM-dd-yyy"));
    }

    if( r.getColumn() == 6 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      //if( nextCell.getValue() !== 'COMPLETE') 
      nextCell.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "MM-dd-yyy HH:mm:ss"));

    }
  }
}
```

If anyone could help me with this please let me know.

Comment: Add a screenshot of your spreadsheet in order to be able to check that your code is using the right sheet name and column values.. Beside that consider to add some [console.log](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/console#log) in order to help you to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s, cols, offset, ind;
s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
cols = [2, 6];
offset = [1, 2];
ind = cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
if (s.getName() == "Notes" && (ind == 0 || ind == 1 && e.range.offset(0, 1).getValue() == 'COMPLETE')) {
    e.range.offset(0, offset[ind]).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "MM-dd-yyy HH:mm:ss"));
    }
}
```

Note that this script runs on a simple on Edit trigger. Do not try to run if from the script editor. Instead, try editing the designated columns and see if the timestamp appears.