# Automatically record start time, end time and total handling time in Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can anyone help me with an Apps Script in Google sheets that would automatically record start time in column I as soon as there is an input in column B as shown in the image below?

[1st image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS4pF.png)

Then, automatically add an end time in column J once the "done" option is clicked on column H as shown on the image below

[2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJdbu.png)

Do nothing or continuously record the time once "pend" option is chosen as shown on the screenshot below.

[3rd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFlKl.png)

Lastly, automatically calculate the total handling time as shown on the screenshot on column K.

Appreciate any responses.

//Edited question for suspend and resume function

[time tracker sheets view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT9PS.png)

As you can see, marking it done (let end) will just mark the end time. What I'm trying to do is add another validation in column H such as suspend and resume. Suspend will stop or somehow record the suspended time and then resume will just continue the time tracking.

Comment: Start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If you need further help, please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I'm unable to post what I've tried so far it says too long. it also doesn't seem to work but I'm working on the function onEdit(e)

Comment: You might have to learn to create [mcve]... regarding recording a timestamp this site already has a lot of questions about that i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/q/53451185/1595451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.value) {
    e.range.offset(0, 6).setValue(new Date())
  }
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 8 && e.value) {
    e.range.offset(0, 2).setValue(new Date());
    let Start = new Date(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,8).getValue());
    let End = new Date(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,9).getValue());
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,10).setValue(timeDiff1(Start,End));
  }

}

function timeDiff1(Start, End) {
  if (Start && End) {
    var second = 1000;
    var minute = 60 * second;
    var t1 = new Date(Start).valueOf();
    var t2 = new Date(End).valueOf();
    var d = t2 - t1;
    var minutes = Math.floor(d % day % hour / minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor(d % day % hour % minute / second);
    return 'mm:ss\n' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
  }
  else {
    return 'Invalid Inputs';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to work with only minor issues. It returns the whole timediff function below in column J

 "function timeDiff1(Start, End) {
  if (Start && End) {
    var second = 1000;
    var minute = 60 * second;
    var t1 = new Date(Start).valueOf();
    var t2 = new Date(End).valueOf();
    var d = t2 - t1;
    var minutes = Math.floor(d % day % hour / minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor(d % day % hour % minute / second);
    return 'mm:ss\n' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
  }
  else {
    return 'Invalid Inputs';
  }
}"

Comment: Also, it records both date and time in column I, is there a way to record the time only?

Comment: Sorry I had to complete all of the timeDiff() function call which I mistakenly omitted the firist time

Comment: I don't believe that the function writes anything in column I

Comment: Great! It's not writing the entire function now but it's still writing the date and time is it possible to write date and time only?

It does write the start time (Date & Time) in column I and it also writes the end time in column J (Date & Time).

Also it does not automatically calculate the total time in column K

Comment: oh i can just set the number format for that column into time (hh:mm:ss)

Comment: Ok, I think we're on the last issue.  it doesn't automatically calculate the duration start time - end time on column K

Comment: oh nvm I can just fix it by adding some forumulas to the cell. Thank you so much!

Comment: Just a follow up question though. Why does the on edit function not trigger to other users?

Comment: I think it does

Comment: Hi Cooper, appreciate you guiding me on this. I have one last thing though, is there a way we can suspend the time tracking and then have the option to resume it anytime?

Comment: It would be handy to have a checkbox somewhere convenient for you so that you could enable and disable it.  Can you imagine a place for it?

Comment: I've updated the question so I can send an image. I was thinking of embedding it to validation rule just like I did on the screenshot or whichever you think is doable. Do you know if it's possible?

Comment: You have change the question too much.  I no longer wish to provide any additional answers.

Comment: Alright, appreciate you looking into this buddy.