# How to pause and resume timer in Google sheets handling time tracker using onEdit function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a simple time tracker for time and motion study purposes in Google sheets. The current code that I'm using only records start time and end time as shown on the screenshot below.

[Time tracker][image: 1]

What I would like to do is for it to have the ability to pause the timer and then have the ability to resume anytime.

Below is the current script/code I'm using (Credits to @Cooper who provided me this code in [Automatically record start time, end time and total handling time in Google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73298378/automatically-record-start-time-end-time-and-total-handling-time-in-google-shee/73298913?noredirect=1#comment130060240_73298913):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.value) {
    e.range.offset(0, 7).setValue(new Date())
  }
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 8 && e.value) {
    e.range.offset(0, 2).setValue(new Date());
    let Start = new Date(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,8).getValue());
    let End = new Date(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,9).getValue());
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,10).setValue(timeDiff1(Start,End));
  }

}

function timeDiff1(Start, End) {
  if (Start && End) {
    var second = 1000;
    var minute = 60 * second;
    var t1 = new Date(Start).valueOf();
    var t2 = new Date(End).valueOf();
    var d = t2 - t1;
    var minutes = Math.floor(d % day % hour / minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor(d % day % hour % minute / second);
    return 'mm:ss\n' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
  }
  else {
    return 'Invalid Inputs';
  }
}
```

Is this doable or is there an alternative code I can use?

Comment: I have an idea - *kind of*, hence the comment. Add another column where you set the time you make the pause (*let's call it:  `pause_time`*), then, after you resume, check the current value of the cell that has the `pause_time` and get the time difference between the `pause_time` time and the `new Date()` = this is your resume date. This result will be updated on the "Handling time" cell.

Comment: that is a great idea I think that would work but I'm fairly new to writing scripts and have no idea how to write do it, can you help please?